# What is the simplest way to get a ratio in PHP of multiple numbers?

Tags: php, math, function, recursion

I've adapted this from an example that I found on the 'net...

```
function ratio($a, $b) {
    $_a = $a;
    $_b = $b;

    while ($_b != 0) {

        $remainder = $_a % $_b;
        $_a = $_b;
        $_b = $remainder;   
    }

    $gcd = abs($_a);

    return ($a / $gcd)  . ':' . ($b / $gcd);

}

echo ratio(9, 3); // 3:1
```

Now I want it to use `func_get_args()` and return the ratios for multiple numbers. It looks like a recursive problem, and recursion freaks me out (especially when my *solutions* infinitely loop)!

How would I modify this to take as many parameters as I wanted?

Thanks

Comment: take it from c answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527860/calculate-a-ratio-in-c

Comment: What do you mean with 'the ratios for multiple numbers'? Something like `2 : 3 : 5`?

What you could do is first compute the prime factorizations for each item in the list of numbers. The product of the prime factors in the intersection is the greatest common denominator. The respective ratios are then computed just like in your example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1st, try this gcd function http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-gcd.php
    Or else you must define a gcd function like

```
    function gcd($a, $b) {
        $_a = abs($a);
        $_b = abs($b);

        while ($_b != 0) {

            $remainder = $_a % $_b;
            $_a = $_b;
            $_b = $remainder;   
        }
        return $a;
    }
```

Then modify the ratio function

```
    function ratio()
    {
        $inputs = func_get_args();
        $c = func_num_args();
        if($c < 1)
            return ''; //empty input
        if($c == 1)
            return $inputs[0]; //only 1 input
        $gcd = gcd($input[0], $input[1]); //find gcd of inputs
        for($i = 2; $i < $c; $i++) 
            $gcd = gcd($gcd, $input[$i]);
        $var = $input[0] / $gcd; //init output
        for($i = 1; $i < $c; $i++)
            $var .= ':' . ($input[$i] / $gcd); //calc ratio
        return $var; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Is GMD installed on most PHP installations?