# C# find the greatest common divisor

Tags: c#, math

"The greatest common divisor of two integers is the largest integer that evenly divides each of the two numbers. Write method Gcd that returns the greatest common divisor of two integers. Incorporate the method into an app that reads two values from the user and displays the result."

(this is not homework, just an exercise in the book I'm using)

can you help me solve this? Here's what I've got so far.

(edit - I can submit the two numbers but it won't calculate the Gcd for me)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Greatest_Common_Divisor
{
class Program
{

    static int GetNum(string text)
    {
        bool IsItANumber = false;
        int x = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        do
        {
            IsItANumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);

        } while (!IsItANumber);

        return x;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "enter a number";
        int x = GetNum(text);
        text = "enter a second number";
        int y = GetNum(text);


        int z = GCD(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }

    private static int GCD(int x, int y)
    {
        int v = 0;
        int n = 0;

        v = GetGreatestDivisor(x, y);


        return v;

    }

    static int GetGreatestDivisor(int m, int h)
        {

            do
            {
                for (int i = m; i <= 1; i--)



                    if (m%i == 0 && h%i == 0)
                    {
                        int x = 0;
                        x = i;

                        return x;
                    }
            } while (true);
            return m;
        }

  }
}
```

Comment: I can submit the two numbers but it won't calculate the Gcd for me

Comment: You should check out the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: `for (int i = m; i <= 1; i--)` won't execute when `m > 1`, you meant `i >= 1`.

Answer (score 102):

Here's an implementation of the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) that returns the greatest common divisor without performing any heap allocation.

You can substitute `ulong` for `uint` if needed. An unsigned type is used, as the technique does not work for signed values. If you know your `a` and `b` values are not negative, you can use `long` or `int` instead.

```
private static ulong GCD(ulong a, ulong b)
{
    while (a != 0 && b != 0)
    {
        if (a > b)
            a %= b;
        else
            b %= a;
    }

    return a | b;
}
```

This method is used in my [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/blob/master/MetadataExtractor/Rational.cs#L295) library, where it has associated [unit tests](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/blob/master/MetadataExtractor.Tests/RationalTest.cs#L264).

Comment: This is the best answer on the page; it does not do any expensive and extraneous recursive calls, and actually answers the OP's specific question (unlike a few other answers which for some reason digress on GCD of a set).

Comment: They compute the GCD of a set because they're copying and pasting code they don't understand from an answer to a separate question.

Comment: Nice and clean - no LINQ-soup mixed in. And with that, exactly what I was looking for my own little "dilemma". :D

Comment: Oh, this does work just fine with negative input(s): just flip the sign of negative values before entering the while-loop... if(a<0)a=-a; if(b<0)b=-b;

Comment: Last line can be writen: "return a | b;"  . As one of them will always be zero, performing an OR operation with both will result the non-zero value.

Comment: Good idea. It avoids a branch.

Answer (score 29):

Using LINQ's Aggregate method:

```
static int GCD(int[] numbers)
{
    return numbers.Aggregate(GCD);
}

static int GCD(int a, int b)
{
    return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
}
```

Note: answer above borrowed from accepted answer to [Greatest Common Divisor from a set of more than 2 integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635564/greatest-common-divisor-from-a-set-of-more-than-2-integers).

Comment: This is incorrect. You can't split this answer into LINQ and non-LINQ, the solution is the 2 methods working together. The first method is calling the second method in the Aggregate call, this is a bit confusing because the names are the same.

Comment: it would be very nice to reply to this, Karl. Your answer is indeed incorrect.

Comment: @DonLarynx  Is this answer still incorrect after the most recent edit? Seems like at least the second function works to me, but I could definitely be wrong.

Answer (score 11):

You can try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635564/greatest-common-divisor-from-a-set-of-more-than-2-integers):

```
static int GreatestCommonDivisor(int[] numbers)
{
    return numbers.Aggregate(GCD);
}

static int GreatestCommonDivisor(int x, int y)
{
return y == 0 ? x : GreatestCommonDivisor(y, x % y);
}
```

Comment: return x*y == 0 ? x : GreatestCommonDivisor(y, x % y);  this version has more accurate

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
public static int GCD(int p, int q)
{
    if(q == 0)
    {
         return p;
    }

    int r = p % q;

    return GCD(q, r);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution.
You can use [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-5.0) to get the greatest common divisor. Just **do not** forget to add `using System.Numerics;` to the top of your code.

```
using System.Numerics;

public class Program{
    public static void Main(String[] args){
        int n1 = 1;
        int n2 = 2;

        BigInteger gcd = BigInteger.GreatestCommonDivisor(n1,n2);
        Console.WriteLine(gcd);
    }
}
```

[Offical Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.greatestcommondivisor?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class GCD 
{        
    public int generalizedGCD(int num, int[] arr)
    {
         int gcd = arr[0]; 

        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
            gcd = getGcd(arr[i], gcd); 
        }

        return gcd; 
    }    
    public int getGcd(int x, int y) 
    { 
        if (x == 0) 
            return y; 
        return getGcd(y % x, x); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
By using this, you can pass multiple values as well in the form of array:-


// pass all the values in array and call findGCD function
    int findGCD(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
        int gcd = arr[0]; 
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            gcd = getGcd(arr[i], gcd); 
}

        return gcd; 
    } 

// check for gcd
int getGcd(int x, int y) 
    { 
        if (x == 0) 
            return y; 
        return gcd(y % x, x); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency is not a big concern this will do the job.

```
// gets greatest common divisor of A and B. 
var GCD=Enumerable.Range(1,Math.Min(A,B)).Last(n=>(A%n | B%n)==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> gcd = new List<int>();
int n1, n2;

bool com = false;

Console.WriteLine("Enter first number: ");
n1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter second number: ");
n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = 1; i <= n1; i++)
{
    if(n1 % i == 0 && n2% i == 0)
    {
        gcd.Add(i);
    }

    if(i == n1)
    {
        com = true;
    }
}

if(com == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GCD of {0} and {1} is {2}.", n1, n2, gcd[gcd.Count - 1]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] nums = new int[] {6,12,24,48};
int GCD(int a, int b) => b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
int FindGCD(int[] numbers) => numbers.Aggregate(GCD);

Console.WriteLine($"List of numbers ({String.Join(',',nums)})");
Console.WriteLine($"Smallest number: {nums.Min()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Largest number: {nums.Max()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Greatest common devisor of {nums.Min()} and {nums.Max()}: {GCD(nums.Min(),nums.Max())}");
Console.WriteLine($"Aggregate common devisor of array ({String.Join(',',nums)}): {FindGCD(nums)}");
```

List of numbers (6,12,24,48)

Smallest number: 6

Largest number: 48

Greatest common devisor of 6 and 48: 6

Aggregate common devisor of array (6,12,24,48): 6

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Program
{
    public static int GETGCD(int[] a)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int answer = 0;
        while (index < a.Length)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
            {
                if (a[x] % a[index] == 0)
                {
                    answer = a[index];
                }
                else
                {
                    answer = 0;
                    x += a.Length;
                }
            }
            if (answer == 0)
            {
                index++;
            }
            if (answer != 0)
            {
                index += a.Length;
            }

        }
        if (answer == 0)
        {
            answer = 1;
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        int[] b = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };

        Console.WriteLine("Greatest Common Divisor of {" + String.Join(",", a.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()) + "} is " + GETGCD(a));
        Console.WriteLine("Greatest Common Divisor of {" + String.Join(",", b.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()) + "} is " + GETGCD(b));
    }
}
```

This is fully running code. Just copy and paste it. Screenshot of the output is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is my method

```cs
// long and simple write :
int gcd(int u, int v)
{
    if (v != 0)
    {
        return gcd(v, u % v);
    }
    return u;
}

// short and complex write :
int gcd(int u, int v) => ((v != 0) ? gcd(v, u % v) : u);
```

my gist in guthub about it is : https://gist.github.com/AmirMahdyJebreily/2c0e7c05f642af18c3bd6d58a915bfdc

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;

//Write a function that returns the greatest common divisor (GCD) of two integers

namespace GCD_of_Two_Numbers
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Gcd(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int[] temp1 = new int[num1];
            int[] temp2 = new int[num2];
            int[] common = new int[10];

            for(int i=2;i<num1/2;i++)
            {
                if(num1 % i ==0)
                {
                    temp1[i] = i;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 2; i < num2/2; i++)
            {
                if (num2 % i == 0)
                {
                    temp2[i] = i;
                }
            }
            int len = temp1.Length + temp2.Length;
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                if(temp1[i]==temp2[i])
                {
                    common[i] = temp1[i];
                }
            }

            int max_number = common[0];
            for(int i=0;i<common.Length;i++)
            {
                if(max_number < common[i])
                {
                    max_number = common[i];
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"The Greatest Common Diviser is {max_number}");
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Gcd(32, 8);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    int a=789456;


    int b=97845645;
    if(a>b)     
    {

    }
    else
    {
        int temp=0;
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    int x=1;
    int y=0 ;

    for (int i =1 ; i < (b/2)+1 ; i++ )
    {

        if(a%i==0)
        {
             x=i;
        }
        if(b%i==0)
        {
             y=i;
        }
        if ((x==y)& x==i & y==i & i < a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

    }
```