# Is there a java equivalent to C#'s .Aggregate(foo) method?

Tags: java, c#

I'm trying to implement the accept answer in this question in java:

[Greatest Common Divisor from a set of more than 2 integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635564/greatest-common-divisor-from-a-set-of-more-than-2-integers)

But I don't know how to implement the aggregate function.

Comment: Can you give us an example what are you trying to do. a math example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a one-liner when using Java 8:

```
public class GCD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ints = { 42, 21, 14, 70 };
        System.out.println(gcd(ints));
    }
    public static int gcd(int[] ints) {
        return Arrays.stream(ints).reduce((a, b) -> gcd(a, b)).getAsInt();
    }
    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

Output is "7". The aggregate function is called a *reduction*.

Alternative: The lambda can also be written with a method reference.

```
public static int gcd(int[] ints) {
    return Arrays.stream(ints).reduce(GCD::gcd).getAsInt();
}
```

Comment: Accepted answer because it does work but I was hoping there would be a j7 solution.

Comment: The aggregation is not part of the language specification. Streams and all those operations on streams are parts of the Java 8 libraray. In previous versions you must implement them yourself or use Guava (they have also some nice features for that). Unfortunately, you don't have lambdas then.