# Using a stream to produce a tuple of lists from a list of tuples

Tags: java

I am trying to find how to create a tuple of lists from a list of tuples.
for example

`f(list<tuple<u,v>>) => tuple<list<u>,list<v>>`

This use case does not appear to be accommodated well by the standard API.
[Other articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948997/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-cs-aggregatefoo-method) say to use `reduce`, but this does not work since it will only return the same type as the input type.

[In .net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__System_Func___1___2__) I would use `Enumerable.Aggregate` to achieve this.

Is there a functional way to achieve this in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java12 will provide `Collectors.teeing` which allows to apply two collectors and then merge their results

Meanwhile, you can apply `reduce`

```
Tuple<List<U>,List<V>> tupleOfLists = listOfTuples
  .stream()
  .reduce(
    new Tuple<List<U>,List<V>>(new ArrayList<U>(), new ArrayList<V>()),
    (tupleOfLists, tuple) -> {
      tupleOfLists.left().add(tuple.left());          
      tupleOfLists.right().add(tuple.right());
      return tupleOfLists;
    },
    (tupleOfLists1, tupleOfLists2) -> {
      tupleOfLists1.left().addAll(tupleOfLists2.left());
      tupleOfLists1.right().addAll(tupleOfLists2.right());
      return  tupleOfLists1;
    }
  );
```

Comment: This does not appear to work since the method `reduce` is defined as `T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator);`. Which means that the lambda of `(tupleOfLists, tuple)` is not of type `(<Tuple<List<U>,List<V>>, Tuple<U,V>)`, it is `(Tuple<U,V>, Tuple<U,V>)`

Comment: Updated. It should use reduce with 3 parameters

Comment: This third is required in case you run parallel stream. If you know you will never run parallel then you can use `(tupleOfLists1, tupleOfLists2) -> tupleOfLists1` or even dummy `(t1,t2)->null`

Comment: I missed that overload. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you would need to use Java 12, to write something like:

```
listOfTuples.stream().collect(teeing(
  map(t -> t.u).collect(Collectors.toList()),
  map(t -> t.v).collect(Collectors.toList()), 
  (us, vs) -> new Tuple(us,vs)
 ));
```

Haven't done this myself - just found a similare example here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors

Comment: `teeing` will accept two collectors, I do not think you could use `map` here.

Comment: I would say it could be 

.teeing(
toList(), 
toList(), 
(a,b) -> new Tuple(a.map(Tuple::left).collect(toList()), b.map(Tuple::right).collect(toList()))

Comment: Or even better you first write your own `mapping collector` and then `teeing(mapAndCollect(Tuple::left), mapAndCollect(Tuple::right), (a,b) -> new Tuple(a,b))`