# C# : How to calculate aspect ratio

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspect-ratio

I am relatively new to programming. I need to calculate the aspect ratio(16:9 or 4:3) from a given dimension say axb. How can I achieve this using C#. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
public string AspectRatio(int x, int y)
{
 //code am looking for
 return ratio
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Get the width to height ratio

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate a Ratio in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527860/calculate-a-ratio-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @V4Vendetta and it containts only the same not-so-good solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to find Greatest Common Divisor, and divide both x and y by it.

```
static int GCD(int a, int b)
{
    int Remainder;

    while( b != 0 )
    {
        Remainder = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = Remainder;
    }

    return a;
}

return string.Format("{0}:{1}",x/GCD(x,y), y/GCD(x,y));
```

**PS**

If you want it to handle something like 16:10 (which can be divided by two, 8:5 will be returned using method above) you need to have a table of predefined `((float)x)/y`-aspect ratio pairs

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try it out.

Comment: This fails for the ratio `16:10`... ;)

Comment: Poor notebook users with 1366x768 resolution =(

Answer (score 6):

Since you only need to decide between 16:9 and 4:3, here's a much simpler solution.

```
public string AspectRatio(int x, int y)
{
    double value = (double)x / y;
    if (value > 1.7)
        return "16:9";
    else
        return "4:3";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There're only several standard ratios like: `4:3`, `5:4`, `16:10`, `16:9`.
`GCD` is a good idea, but it will fail for at least `16:10` ratios and `1366x768` resolution.

Pure GCD algorithm will get `683:384` for 1366x768, cause 683 is a prime, while resolution is almost 16:9 (16.0078125).

I suppose, that for real tasks, one will need to implement rather complicated algorithm:

First try known aspect ratios (look for them at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions)), allowing some errors and only then use GCD as fallback.

Don't forget about [32:10](https://www.google.ru/search?q=crvd+display) ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes there are few exceptional cases like you mentioned

Comment: @kirilloid I've been using GCD and am looking for insight on those "rather complicated algorithms". Do you know where to start for something more thorough?

Comment: @TR3B find the best approximation with small (<=20) denominator and then use additional custom mappings like 8:5 is actually 16:10 or 39:18 is actually 19.5:9 (some modern smartphones). Google various screen resolutions, read on wikipedia, to get insights.

Comment: So it all comes down to this... Why are we all talking about calculating AR when you can't cover all the specifications without mapping?

Comment: Because there is much fewer aspect ratios than resolutions. And even fewer exceptions. Good luck enumerating all exceptions, esp. if you are looking for dp (device-independent pixels), with custom settings—they are just non-GCD-able.

Comment: I think that aged well with introduction of long smartphones with 19:9, 19.5:9, 20:9 etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the GCD (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) and then:

```
return x/GCD + ":" + y/GCD;
```

Comment: This fails for the ratio `16:10`... ;)

Comment: `16:10` also known as `8:5` :)