# How calculate aspect ratio from dimensions of image

Tags: c#, javascript, image, aspect-ratio

I am using Jcrop for cropping image so i want to calculate ratio of height and width of image but problem is that there is no limit of maximum height and width.

when user upload image then  i want to get height,width ratio so on cropping it should be crop with respect to aspect ratio for example

> Width=835, Height=625 aspect ratio would be 167: 125

i have calculated this ratio from following link
[Aspect ratio calculator](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/)

I don't want to cacalute new height,width. I just want to calculate ratio 167: 125

How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Calculate a Ratio in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527860/calculate-a-ratio-in-c-sharp)

Comment: not sure where you got 107:90.  I put those numbers into that site and got 167:125.  Regardless, just follow the math on the site you linked and you'll be able to get any image ratio.

Comment: yes i have correct the ratio 167: 125

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for HCF (Highest Common Factor) but the ratio (Width:835,Height:625) will be 167:125.
Here is the function by which you can calculate HCF between 2 numbers.

```
 private int FindHCF(int m, int n)
 {
     int temp, remainder;
     if (m < n)
     {
         temp = m;
         m = n;
         n = temp;
     }
     while (true)
     {
         remainder = m % n;
         if (remainder == 0)
             return n;
         else
             m = n;
         n = remainder;
     }
 }
```

So here is the rest of the code

```
int hcf = FindHcf(835, 625);
int factorW = 835 / hcf;
int factorH = 625 / hcf;
```